# Call Cocoa ObjC method from NSEvent Block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Why doesn't this code work:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSScrollWheelMask) handler:^(struct NSEvent *event){
        [scrollEvent:event];
    }];
}

- (void)scrollEvent:event {
    NSLog( @"scroll" );
}
```

It says "'scrollEvent' undeclared".

I'm just learning objc and cocoa, so I assume this is just a simple error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code appears to have some bugs in it. I've cleaned up some, please see below.

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *) aNotification { 
    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: NSScrollWheelMask handler:^(NSEvent *event){ 
        [self scrollEvent: event]; 
    }]; 
} 

- (void) scrollEvent: (NSEvent *) event { 
    NSLog( @"scroll" ); 
}
```

To summarize:

- Your argument to the block should have been an `NSEvent *`, not a
  `struct NSEvent *`.
- Your invocation of scrollEvent needed to be sent to self.
- Your implementation of scrollEvent had an incorrect signature.

Hope that helps and good luck with the program.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your :event parameter of the scrollEvent method needs to have a type (NSEvent*) for this to be a valid method signature.

```
- (void)scrollEvent:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog( @"scroll" );
}
```